# How to plot similarity of two datasets?

Tags: plotting

I'm performing some simulations, and at the end I get a CSV file with three columns. One column holds the values for the x-axis, which was also input to the simulation and theoretical calculations, second one holds theoretically expected values, and the other column holds the values obtained by the simulation. I was planning to plot something like this:

[image]

But that does not look good in my case, as the values in y-axis normally keep doubling, and the values for the x-axis exponentially increase, so most of the points end up getting collected at the lower left part, near the intersection of x-axis and y-axis of the plot. Therefore, I need a different way to plot my data, which will be more visually appealing and inform how close the simulation results are to the theoretical expected ones. For example, some of my values can be seen below (and they keep increasing in such a way):

```
x         = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64] # partially removed for brevity
expected  = [47.9995, 95.9783, 191.9127, 383.9708, 767.8831] # partially removed for brevity 
simulated = [48, 96, 191.8, 383.8, 767.4] # partially removed for brevity
```

What is a good way to plot such a data that doubles in the y-axis and exponentially increases on the x-axis all the time, and to view how similar the two datasets actually are?

Comment: Plotting the logarithm of x with the difference between the actual and simulated values will do?

Comment: @Aditya You mean to take logarithm of every element in `x` array, and take element-wise difference of elements in `expected` and `simulated` arrays?

Comment: Exactly but it seems that it will be depending on `max(x)`, Can you add some more of `x` or tell us the order of x's

Comment: @Aditya I goes as much as 11-12 digit numbers.

Comment: From your plot, it seemed that your model is doing amazing work but it seems that it's highly accurate as it's even mapping some of them lying here and there(seperate from the main cluster) Why it's so?

Comment: @Aditya what do you mean exactly? Please note that the figure is not mine, only the provided values are mine.

Comment: Oh the fig doesn't belong to you..What I meant is that on zooming the plot a bit, all the original values matches with the expected values nearly and overlap considerably(this can be seen more clearly by setting the `aplha` values..So I was wondering about the model architecture, Preprocessing and all related stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of `r` lattice `xyplot` using log scale on the x axis and the difference of your two measures `I(expected - simulated)`

```
df <- data.frame(
x         = c(2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64),
expected  = c(47.9995, 95.9783, 
191.9127, 383.9708, 767.8831, 
1457.2771),
simulated = c(48, 96, 191.8, 383.8, 
767.4, 1458.1228))
xy <- xyplot(I(expected - simulated) ~ x ,   
auto.key=TRUE,
data =  df ,    type=c("p","g"),
scales=list(x=list(log = 10) ),   
ylab="difference expected - simulated", xlab="x", main="Simulation Results" )
print (xy)
```

Note, that I added a 6th result to your sample data,that was missing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here we have `50000` points, `10000` in each of `five` categories with associated numerical values.

Instead of using Logarithms, you can also use 
`O( log* N )` is "[iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm)":

> In computer science, the iterated logarithm of n, written log* n (usually read "log star"), is the number of times the logarithm function must be iteratively applied before the result is less than or equal to 1.

Checkout **Datashader** (This is what you Need)

[Reference Notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/A2%20-%20Visualizing%20Big%20Data%20with%20Datashader.ipynb)

> Generating Something Random(you will get the idea)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
num=10000

dists = {cat: pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.normal(x,s,num),
                                y=np.random.normal(y,s,num),
                                val=val,cat=cat))
         for x,y,s,val,cat in 
         [(2,2,0.01,10,"d1"), (2,-2,0.1,20,"d2"), (-2,-2,0.5,30,"d3"), (-2,2,1.0,40,"d4"), (0,0,3,50,"d5")]}

df = pd.concat(dists,ignore_index=True)
df["cat"]=df["cat"].astype("category")
df.tail()
```

`cat val     x           y
49995   d5  50  -1.397579   0.610189
49996   d5  50  -2.649610   3.080821
49997   d5  50  1.933360    0.243676
49998   d5  50  4.306374    1.032139
49999   d5  50  -0.493567   -2.242669`

```
%time tf.shade(ds.Canvas().points(df,'x','y'))
```

> Output Image

[image: The Picture Clearly Shows 5 Normal Distributions]