# How to plot clusters in nice a way?

Tags: clustering, text-mining, plotting, matplotlib

I have a large text dataset clusterized. Each cluster is represented by a centroid of the vectorized texts that belong to it, the number of texts, the created date, and other parameters. I can't plot the clusters in an n-dimensional space. Which options do I have?

Comment: Search for holoviews

Comment: that bib is great @Aditya!

Comment: A sample plot using datashader from the same.. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/28659/35644 @Federico Caccia

Answer (score 3):

T-SNE is another dimensionality reduction algorithm not mentioned in the article in the other answer. Used for VERY high dimensional data, if you have trained some embeddings for your dataset. [Reference Here](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) . Python standard library [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html).

cheers

Answer (score 3):

Several options:

- [Locally Linear Embedding (LLE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction#Locally-linear_embedding): This method construct a set of local geometric patches on each of which a data point is reconstructed through the weighted sum of its K nearest neighbor and maps these patches into a lower dimensional space. [Find the code here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_compare_methods.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-manifold-plot-compare-methods-py) and I strongly advice to use both LLE and [Modified LLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction#Modified_Locally-Linear_Embedding_(MLLE)) and use the better one (visually).
- [t-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding): Maps the similarity of points in high-dimension, into a low dimensional manifold extracted by their distance in t-distribution. [Be careful to tune parameters properly](https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/).
- [Spectral Embedding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.SpectralEmbedding.html#sklearn.manifold.SpectralEmbedding): [Spectral Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering) in fact (or to be precise, Spectral Clustering is indeed a simple clustering on Spectrally Embedded version of data). It projects the data on eigenvectors of its [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) according to the magnitude of corresponding eigenvalues.

an many more ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dimensionality reduction algorithm (like principal component analysis) to reduce the number of dimensions of the data to 2 or 3, and then perform scatter plots using the reduced variables, coloring them according to the cluster they belong to. In [this blogpost](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/02/qlucore-comparison-pca-hierarchical-clustering.html) a similar thing is done.

Comment: I have thousands of dimensions, so PCA could become in too much loss of information. And I just want to plot the centroids of each cluster. I think the best way is to plot creation time vs another feature, and give to the point(bubble) a radius proportional to the amount of elements in this cluster.